# Open embedded mpp file in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I do have project file(mpp) embedded as object in my excel file. My vba script below that will open the embedded file. But stuck and received runtime error in this line --> `oEmbFile.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary`
.

Thank you in advance

```
Private Sub Project_Click()
Dim x As MSProject.Application
Dim oEmbFile As Object
 
 
'// Opens object
 
 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set oEmbFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Execution_plan").OLEObjects("Object 1")
oEmbFile.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Look for existing instance
On Error Resume Next
Set x = GetObject("Project.Application")

 
AppActivate ("Microsoft Project")
Set x = Nothing
Set oEmbFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobject.activate) method instead. You could do something like this where you try the [Verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobject.verb) method first and if if fails, try the Activate method:

```
Private Sub Project_Click()
Dim x As MSProject.Application
Dim oEmbFile As OLEObject
 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set oEmbFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Execution_plan").OLEObjects("Object 1")
On Error Resume Next
oEmbFile.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    oEmbFile.Activate
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Look for existing instance
Set x = GetObject("Project.Application")

AppActivate ("Microsoft Project")
Set x = Nothing
Set oEmbFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. :). I tried but it didn't work and no error message. Nothing happens when I ran the button